# Upgrading a multi-project workspace with angular cli (v7 - v8)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a multi-project workspace created using angular cli v7, that contains several packages, and a demo application. The structure is something like:

```
projects/npm_scope/package_name_one/..
projects/npm_Scope/package_name_two/..
src/app/..
```

The packages were generated using the `ng generate library @npm_scope/package_name_one` etc

The demo app under src was created when generating the workspace originally using `ng new`

I'm now attempting to upgrade this workspace to angular v8 using the cli upgrade helper. Unfortunately the instructions here https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0 do not mention anything about working with multi-project workspaces, and following these instructions does not apply any of the migrations to my packages. I ran:

```
npx @angular/cli update --all --force
```

Which completed without error, but only altered files in the `src/app/` directory, when I know for a fact that the packages contain files that should have had migrations applied to them.

Is it possible to run this update command in such a way that migrations are applied to all projects in the workspace? Or do I have to try and manually migrate these projects?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14472 - I found this issue which seems related, it seems that perhaps the migrations don't apply to my library files, and that it is expected that you would manually update library `package.json` files. I guess that the `tsconfig.json` files aren't supposed to be changed either